# How can I remove ws.name

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to create a PDF file using following script, it works but when I remove `ws.Name`, the script breaks.

```
Sub createPDFfiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strName As String
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next 'Continue if an error occurs

        ' Name PDF files based on the worksheet Index (e.g Annex 1.1.1, Annex 1.1.2, etc.)
        strName = Range("A10").Text & " " & Range("C7").Text & ws.Name


        ' If you want to name the PDF files differently just change the Fname variable above to
        ' whatever you like. For example if you changed Fname to:
        '
        '  Fname =  "C:\myFolder\pdfs\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "-" & ws.Name
        '
        '  The files would be stored in C:\myFolder\pdfs, and named using the
        ' spreadsheet file name and the worksheet name.
        '
        ' WARNING: Using worksheet names may cause errors if the  names contain characters that Windows
        ' does not accept in file names. See below for a list of characters that you need to avoid.
        '
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=strName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

How can I remove this `ws.Name` and still work?

Comment: You have to have a file name. If you don't want to use the worksheet name as the file name, use something else.

Comment: That is a simplified variable for "Worksheet" function so you don't have to write "Worksheet" everytime you instantiate creating PDF from Excel.

Comment: Never use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling! This just hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur you just cannot see them. It's like closing your eyes. You cannot debug a code that uses `On Error Resume Next` like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Range` objects are unqualified in this statement:

```
 strName = Range("A10").Text & " " & Range("C7").Text & ws.Name
```

So they are referring to those cells on the active sheet, rather than on sheet `ws`.

If you wanted to refer to those cells on each worksheet you loop through, then qualify them appropriately:

```
 strName = ws.Range("A10").Text & " " & ws.Range("C7").Text
```

You may wish to test that strName is not null before you try to save the PDF.

I'd also recommend losing the `On Error Resume Next` line, and handling errors properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Have a great day ahead. 
On a side note. Even I remove the "on error resume next", error still doesn't show.